# Battery Power Supply w/parallel Voltage Regulators

Tags: parallel

Can this be done?
I need to run a Raspberry Pi off a 12 VDC battery. I have two (2) Voltage Regulators (VR) each regulator uses an AMS1117-5 regulator capable of 5 VDC @ 1 Amp.  The full current draw of the Raspberry Pi (RPi) is 0.65 Amps (650 mA).  I would like to parallel both VR – Both the Input and Output.  I cannot use OR Diodes as the voltage drop across the diode would be too much.  The RPi is very voltage sensitive.  What I hope to gain is a very long battery life for the RPi since the battery is 12 VDC @ 6 AH and a low current draw through each VR.  Note:  The current draw does not have to be balanced since the total current draw is less than the rating of an individual VR.   So  Can it be done?  Safely & somewhat efficiently?   THANK YOU!  Barry

Comment: Won't help - the current from the battery will be the same either way. So as one 1Amp regulator will do the job, there's nothing to gain from using a second one.

Comment: Thanks Brian:  I'm guessing that one VR will conduct a little more or less than the other.  If I split the current even with a 60/40 split I'm hoping for less heat and less of a load on each VR.  Does that sound logical?  I don't want to blow a VR either.  Thanks again Brian.  Barry

Answer (score 1):

Using linear regulators will waste about 4.5 watts, and will require a good heatsink on the regulator(s).

It would be much more efficient (and cooler) to use a switching regulator (DC-DC converter)